# Переключение классов на кнопках к и табах

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку, как сделать переключение табов без `jQuery`.
Есть следующий код.
Необходимо, чтобы при переключении кнопок (стандартные/специальные) добавлялись классы `button_checked` к выбранной кнопке и класс `tabs__tab_active` к активному табу. То есть, должны переключаться кнопки и табы.

Ниже начатый код с ошибками.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs');
const tabsTab = tabs.querySelectorAll('.tabs__tab');
const tabsBtns = tabs.querySelectorAll('.button_tabs');

tabsBtns.forEach(tabsBtn => {
  tabsBtn.addEventListener('click', handleTabsBtnsClick);
});

function handleTabsBtnsClick() {
  const buttons = tabsBtns;
  const tabs = tabsTab;

  toggleButton(buttons);

  toggleTab(tabs);
}

function toggleButton(buttons) {
  buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('button_checked'));

  this.classList.toggle('button_checked');
}

function toggleTab(tabs) {
  tabs.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove('tabs__tab_active'));

  this.classList.toggle('tabs__tab_active');
}
```

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
}

.tabs__tab {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.tabs__list {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.js+bemhtml.js"></script>
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="tabs">
      <span
        class="radio-group radio-group_theme_islands radio-group_size_m radio-group_type_button radio-group_togglable_radio control-group i-bem radio-group_js_inited screen-10__controls"
        data-bem='{"radio-group":{}}'
        role="radiogroup"
      >
        <label
          class="radio radio_type_button radio_theme_islands radio_size_m i-bem"
          data-bem='{"radio":{}}'
        >
          <button
            class="button button_togglable_radio button_theme_islands button_size_m button_checked button__control button_tabs button_tabs_left tabs__button i-bem"
            data-bem='{"button":{}}'
            role="button"
            type="button"
            aria-pressed="false"
          >
            <span class="button__text">Стандартные</span>
          </button>
          <input
            class="radio__control"
            type="radio"
            autocomplete="off"
            name="radio-button"
            value="1"
          />
        </label>
        <label
          class="radio radio_type_button radio_theme_islands radio_size_m i-bem"
          data-bem='{"radio":{}}'
        >
          <button
            class="button button_togglable_radio button_theme_islands button_size_m button__control button_tabs button_tabs_right tabs__button i-bem"
            data-bem='{"button":{}}'
            role="button"
            type="button"
            aria-pressed="false"
          >
            <span class="button__text">Специальные</span>
          </button>
          <input
            class="radio__control"
            type="radio"
            autocomplete="off"
            name="radio-button"
            value="2"
          />
        </label>
      </span>

      <ul class="tabs__list list">
        <li class="tabs__tab tabs__tab_1 tabs__tab_active">
          tab 1
        </li>
        <li class="tabs__tab tabs__tab_2 tabs__tab_active">
          tab 2
          </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов может быть много. Вот, например, при нажатии кнопки удаляем у всех кнопок/табов нужный класс, а потом добавляем его только той кнопке/табе, которая была нажата. Тут главное установить соответствие между кнопкой и определённым табом.
Пример на основе Вашего кода:

```js
const tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs');
const tabsTab = tabs.querySelectorAll('.tabs__tab');
const tabsBtns = tabs.querySelectorAll('.button_tabs');

tabsBtns.forEach(tabsBtn => {
  tabsBtn.addEventListener('click', handleTabsBtnsClick);
});

function handleTabsBtnsClick() {
  toggleButtons.call(this);
  toggleTabs.call(this);
}

function toggleButtons() {
  //Remove button_checked class from all buttons
  tabsBtns.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('button_checked'));
  //Add button_checked class to current button
  this.classList.add('button_checked')
}

function toggleTabs() {
  //Remove tabs__tab_active class from all tabs
  tabsTab.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove('tabs__tab_active'));
  //Find linked tab by date-tab attribute and add tabs__tab_active class
  tabs.querySelector('.' + this.dataset.tab).classList.add('tabs__tab_active');
}
```

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
}

.tabs__tab {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.tabs__list {
  display: flex;
}

.tabs__tab_active {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.button_checked {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.js+bemhtml.js"></script>
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bem-components/latest/desktop/bem-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="tabs">
      <span
        class="radio-group radio-group_theme_islands radio-group_size_m radio-group_type_button radio-group_togglable_radio control-group i-bem radio-group_js_inited screen-10__controls"
      >
        <label
          class="radio radio_type_button radio_theme_islands radio_size_m i-bem"
        >
          <button
            class="button button_togglable_radio button_theme_islands button_size_m button_checked button__control button_tabs button_tabs_left tabs__button i-bem"
            data-tab="tabs__tab_1"
          >
            <span class="button__text">Стандартные</span>
          </button>
        </label>
        <label
          class="radio radio_type_button radio_theme_islands radio_size_m i-bem"
        >
          <button
            class="button button_togglable_radio button_theme_islands button_size_m button__control button_tabs button_tabs_right tabs__button i-bem"
            data-tab="tabs__tab_2"
            >
            <span class="button__text">Специальные</span>
          </button>
        </label>
      </span>

      <ul class="tabs__list list">
        <li class="tabs__tab tabs__tab_1 tabs__tab_active">
          tab 1
        </li>
        <li class="tabs__tab tabs__tab_2">
          tab 2
          </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Думал, уже никто не ответит. Огромная вам благодарность за такой четкий код, да еще, разделенный на отдельные функции (как-будто сам и писал)!!! Благодарю все работает!!! Может знаете какую статью для знакомства со значением this. До этого его не использовал в обработчиках. This в обработчиках всегда ссылается на текущий объект, который вызвал функцию обработчика события?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Можете начать с этого ресурса https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods#klyuchevoe-slovo-this-v-metodah 
Дополнительно ознакомиться https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply и 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Благодарю за информацию!!